# hyperelliptc curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been reading that a hyperelliptic curve is given by $y^{2}=f(x)$.
where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n = 2g + 1 > 4$ or $n = 2g + 2 > 4$ with n distinct roots.
In this case, the curve has genus g.
How to show it (that the curve has genus g)?

I tried to use the genus formula (calculating singularities, etc.) But without success.
It seems to me that the singularities are bad and therefore the calculation becomes difficult.

Comment: Try using Riemann-Hurwitz. This should be straightforward since $f$ has distinct roots (which implies simple branching).

Comment: How to show that the zeros of $ f $ are branch points with index 2?. This is necessary to use Hurwitz. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of the index of a branch point? It is a fact that the index is bounded above by the degree of the cover, that being $2$ here, but that may or may not be obvious from your perspective.